# "Expected Spy Log to have Been Called" issue Javascript

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine

I am having trouble with passing a test spec (below) that after a fetch failure, the spy log would be called. The failure reference is "Expected spy log to have been called". The function I call within handleErrors will output the expected, so the spy log is the only thing I am trying to understand. Any advice would be greatly appreciated! thank you.

```js
//Test 
  it('should recover on fetch error', function(done){
    window.path = "xyz";
    spyOn(console, "log").and.callFake(function(){});

    function check(output) {
      window.path = "xyy";
      expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalled();
      console.log.calls.reset();
      retrieve().then(function(output){
        var expected = {expectedOutput}
        expect(output).toEqual(expected);
        expect(console.log).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        done();
      });
    }

    retrieve().then(check);
  });

//function 
function handleErrors(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
      normalRetrieve()
    }
    return response;
}

//directly after fetch request
.then(handleErrors)
```

Comment: It looks like your test expects retrieve() to write a log message in the failure case, and this isn't happening. When you say "will output the expected" do you mean you are actually getting a log written, it's just not being picked up / consumed by your spy?

Comment: hey Rup! Thanks so much. Just you talking it out made sense. I was logging in an outside function, rather than the retrieve. I added the console.log within the retrieve, and it passed. Thanks so much!